# Mass adding button click events

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to make a script that adds an event listener to every object in an array and on that event listener firing I want it to add the letter associated with that key to be entered onto a label. But when I run the program nothing happens? I can add some dummy code like lblInput.text = "cats"; and it runs fine so the program is definitely running the script.

EDIT: It turns out the button click isn't actually working, why is this I can't see anything wrong with it and there are no errors?

Here is my code:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main() {
            this.addEventListener('enterFrame',function() {
                var buttons:Array = new Array(["Q",btnQ],
                                              ["W",btnW],
                                              ["E",btnE],
                                              ["R",btnR],
                                              ["T",btnT],
                                              ["U",btnY],
                                              ["U",btnU],
                                              ["I",btnI],
                                              ["O",btnO],
                                              ["P",btnP],
                                              ["A",btnA],
                                              ["S",btnS],
                                              ["D",btnD],
                                              ["F",btnF],
                                              ["G",btnG],
                                              ["H",btnH],
                                              ["J",btnJ],
                                              ["K",btnK],
                                              ["L",btnL],
                                              ["Z",btnZ],
                                              ["X",btnX],
                                              ["C",btnC],
                                              ["V",btnV],
                                              ["B",btnB],
                                              ["N",btnN],
                                              ["M",btnM]);  

                for(var i:int = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
                {
                    buttons[i][1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(){

                        if(lblInput.text == "Type something to begin..")
                            lblInput.text = buttons[i][0];
                        else
                            lblInput.appendText(buttons[i][0]);

                    });
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Inside your function `i` is not the value you expect it to be. You need to add a reference of some sort to your button that you can call within your scropt.

Comment: Is this language enough like javascript that I can add a variable to an object by doing object.variable so I could do buttons[i][1].letter = buttons[i][0]

Comment: What type of element are the buttons? MovieClips? That way you can't just add a variable like that I think.

Comment: Yeah they are, how should I store the variable then? Also my button click don't appear to be firing an event at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [putvande](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2539720/putvande) commented, the value of the `i` variable is not what you expect within the event handler. So the easiest thing to do, is make your variable a property of the button which you can then retrieve from the event object within the handler. You said your buttons are movieclips, so that'll work fine because they are extensions of objects.

But seeing as you want a character range, you could do without the array and just specify a range. Especially because you gave all your buttons a generic name plus the desired character.

In your `Main` function:

```
// 65 = capital A in Unicode
// 90 = capital Z in Unicode
var characterRange:Object = {begin:65, end:90};

var character:String;
var button:MovieClip;

for ( var i:int = 0; i < characterRange.end-characterRange.begin; ++i ) {
    // use String.fromCharCode to get "A" from 65 etc.
    character = String.fromCharCode(i + characterRange.begin);
    // get the button based on the character
    button = MovieClip(this.getChildByName("btn"+character));
    // add the character as a property of the button
    button.character = character;
    // attach an click handler
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);
}
```

As the event handler function:

```
function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // get the character/letter from the currently clicked button
    var letter:String = MovieClip(e.currentTarget).character;
    if ( lblInput.text == "Type something to begin..") {
        lblInput.text = letter;
    } else {
        lblInput.appendText(letter);
    }
}
```

Character code examples: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7efe.html